# passing ajax data to codeigniter controller

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-ui, codeigniter

Im trying to pass data from Jquery's selectable function through AJAX and catch it in a codeigniter controller.  No Luck!

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        selected: updatefilters,
        unselected: updatefilters
    });   
    function updatefilters(ev, ui){
        var $selected = $('#selectable').children('.ui-selected');
        var filters = $selected.map(function(){return this.id;}).get().join("|");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'updatefilters',
            data: { filters: filters },
            success: function(data){
                $('#board').replaceWith(data.content);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Controller

```
    public function updatefilters()
    {
        $filters = $this->input->post('data');
        print_r($filters);
        $filterarray = split("|", $filters);
        $this->thread_model->create_session_filter($filterarray); 
        $threads = $this->thread_model->get_threads();
        $data['json'] = '{"content":' + $threads + '}';
        $this->load->view('json_view', $data); // See step 4!!!
    }
```

Views

json_view

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo $json;
?>
```

jquery select view

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="everything">Everything!</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="entertainment">Entertainment</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="sci/tech">Sci/Tech</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="news">News</li>
    <?php 

    if ($this->session->userdata('inactivefilter') == true) {
            $inactivefilter = $this->session->userdata('inactivefilter');
            foreach ($inactivefilter as $new)
                {
                    echo "<li class='ui-state-default' id='custom'>$new</li>";
                }
        }
    ?>
</ol>
```

in Firebug, I can see that the "filter" data being passed via AJAX is not being recognized.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'updatefilters',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { filters: filters },
        success: function(data){
            $('#board').replaceWith(data.content);
        }
    });
```

I just added: **dataType: 'json'**

Greatings.

Comment: I made some headway.  Apparently using | as a delimiter causes problems with PHP.  you need to include a \ in front of it so, \|.